# Как зафиксировать изображение, чтобы оно не оставалось огромным при измене масштаба?

Tags: html, css

Проблема в том, что при изменении масштаба картинка бабочки увеличивается вместе с масштабом, хотя должна оставаться на месте, как и всё остальное

Код html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Сайт</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            var preload = document.getElementById("preloader");
            var loading = 0;
            var id = setInterval(frame, 64);

        function frame() {
            if (loading == 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
            } else {
            loading = loading + 1;
            if (loading == 90) {
          preload.style.opacity = "0";
        }
      }
    }
  })();
</script>

</head>
<body src="pictures/foner.png">
    <li id="text"><a href="">Портфолио</a></li>
    <li id="text"><a href="">Портфолио</a></li>
    <li id="text"><a href="">Портфолио</a></li>

    <img id="logo" src="pictures/logotip.png">
    <img id="fone" src="pictures/fone.png" alt="">
    <img id="foner" src="pictures/fone.png" alt="">
    <p><img id="fon" src="pictures/fon.png" alt=""></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Код css

```
#text {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Comic Sans MS, Comic Sans;
    margin-top: 50px;

}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: grey;
    transition: 2s;
}

a:hover {
    color: black;
    transition: 2s;
}

#logo {
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#fon {
    width: 120%;
    margin-top: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

#fone {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-size: 100%;
}

#foner {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    margin-top: 540px;
    position: absolute;
}

body {
    background-color: purple;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Непонятно по коду, где изображение бабочки. Но мне кажется проблема в относительной ширине, указанной в процентах

```
#fon {
    width: 120%;
    margin-top: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Да, вы правы. Благодарю, вы раскрыли мне глаза